# Installing Theano from Git

Tags: linux, git, theano

When I want to install pylearn2 (and Theano) I use the following command in Linux cluster:

```
git clone git://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2.git
cd pylearn2
python setup.py develop --user
```

However, I see the following error for Theano instllation:

```
Searching for Theano
Best match: Theano [unknown version]
Downloading git+http://github.com/Theano/Theano.git#egg=Theano
error: Download error for git+http://github.com/Theano/Theano.git: unknown url type: git+http
```

I did not find anything on the net regarding this problem. I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install manually the development version of Theano. From this link:

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git --user
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

If for some reason that don't work, clone the repo and install it manually with `pip install .` in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Theano has the following requirements make sure they are met:

```
1) Python >= 2.6
2) g++, python-dev
3) NumPy >= 1.6.2
4) SciPy >= 0.11
5) A BLAS installation (with Level 3 functionality)
```

Then lets  not complicate things and just try

> pip install Theano